# Morphisms of affine line into a curve of higher genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth curve of genus $\geq 1$ over a field $k$.  How does one show that any $k$-morphism $f: \mathbb A^1_k \to X$ has to be constant?  In general, is it true that any morphism $Y \times \mathbb A^1_k \to X$ factors through the projection map $Y \times \mathbb A^1_k \to Y$?

Comment: Hint:For the first question, use Riemann-Hurwitz formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula. The second one has got to do with the definition of fiber product.